# Printing type of auto variable and prototype of template function/method in GDB

Tags: c++, debugging, c++11, gdb

For demonstration purposes I need to print the type of `auto` variables and prototypes of template functions and methods.

How can this be achieved in GDB? Or is there some better way to get this information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick search turned up [this page](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gdb/gdb_116.html), that shows the `whatis` command. Seems to work for me in GDB version 7.0.1.

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't work with functions and methods if they are overloaded. I need something a bit smarter.